# Trouble selecting checkboxes inside each() cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to iterate over each text input field and find out whether a checkbox assigned to it is checked or not. I am having trouble selecting checkboxes inside the each() cycle though.

My HTML:

```
<table>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <label for="MainTemplate" class="">Hlavná šablóna:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="MainTemplate" class="input mainTemplate" value="" style="width: 10em;" type="text"> <br> <table>

    <tbody><tr>         <td>            <input name="MainTemplateInheritCheckbox" class="input inheritCheckbox" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox">        </td>       <td style="font-size: 0.9em;">          <label for="MainTemplateInheritCheckbox">hodnoda sa zdedí z vyššej úrovne</label>       </td>   </tr>

</tbody></table>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <label for="Lector" class="">Školiteľ:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <input name="Lector" class="input lector" value="" style="width: 10em;" type="text"> <br> <table>   <tbody><tr>         <td>            <input name="LectorInheritCheckbox" class="input inheritCheckbox" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox">      </td>       <td style="font-size: 0.9em;">          <label for="LectorInheritCheckbox">hodnoda sa zdedí z vyššej úrovne</label>

        </td>   </tr> </tbody></table>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

My jquery code:

```
        $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
            // here I need to find out whether the checkbox is checked or not
        });
```

I tried this but it returns false even for checked checkboxes:

```
alert($(this).next().next().children("input[type=checkbox]:first").is(":checked"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$(this).next('table').find('input[type=checkbox]:first')is(':checked');`

You could also probably get it by name since they're related.

```
var cbName = '#' + $(this).attr('name') + 'InheritCheckbox';
$(cbName).is(':checked');
```

Both of these are a little bit fragile and depend on relationships either in the DOM or between the element names, though I suspect the latter might be more stable over time.

Comment: Right. The checkbox is a descendant, but not an immediate child, of the node you get to by calling `next` twice. You (=Richard) could also just replace `children` with `find` in your original code, though `.next().next()` looks to me like asking for trouble if the structure of your HTML ever changes even a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this(get the containing table row and search for the checkbox within that element):

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=checkbox]:first").is(":checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:first",$(this).parent()).is(":checked")
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ejCB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function()
{
    alert($(this).closest("td").find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked"));
});
```